# C# - How do you check if object is within a confined area like Ellipse?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, trigonometry

I have a defined ellipse shape, however, can't figure out how to check if a target/object is within this ellipse area.

For example this is what I did to grab objects in defined circle shape. In Unity...

```
Collider2D[] targetsInRadius = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(Circle.position, Radius, targetMask);
```

This only works because circles have a single Radius, However ellipse has two radius where one is longer than the other. does unity have something equivalent to the above code for ellipses.

If it helps I have a Vector3 array containing the vertexes/segment defining the ellipse shape.
how do I check if target is within ellipse?

Comment: Checking if a point is within an ellipse can be done [`like so`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76457/check-if-a-point-is-within-an-ellipse#:~:text=The%20region%20(disk)%20bounded%20by,it%20is%20outside%20the%20ellipse.). Just convert the equation to code and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks very much! This definitely helps :) however, this means I have to track the targets (X,Y) point at all times even outside the ellipse, causing dependency. I was hoping to only track targets within ellipse and not worry whatever is outside it. but this greatly helps!